# Adding eventlistener to javascript array

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to put my markers on google maps and add an InfoWindow to each single marker. I'm getting **Cannot read property 'name' of undefined** on this line after I click on one of the markers:

```
markers[i].name.open(map, marker);
```

Here's the complete script:

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 3,
    // zoom in on current location if available (not done yet...)
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(5,5)
  });

  var markers = [
    // put all markers in a markers array
    @foreach ($markers as $marker)
      new google.maps.Marker({
        position: { lat: {{$marker->x}}, lng: {{$marker->y}} },
        // infowindow for each marker with its name
        name: new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: "{{$marker->name}}"
        })
      }), 
    @endforeach
  ];

  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) { 
    // add eventlistener for the infowindow we added earlier
    google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function() {
      markers[i].name.open(map, marker);
    });
    // add marker to map
    markers[i].setMap(map);
  }
}
```

I'm using Laravel 5.1 with the Blade templating engine.

Comment: logic looks ok , what are u getting if u put console.log(markers) before last for loop ? I don't know much about larvel and blade , but i did this kinda thing in angular. Just see If all markers are there in array before u move to next for loop

Comment: @aishwatsingh Hope this image will do: http://i.imgur.com/CqCQ6Ff.png. The markers show up on the map so they are definitely in the array.

Comment: it's saying that the name property is undefined when you execute the click function on the marker. I would say that the name property requires correct definition. Do you have this running anywhere live?

Comment: @emporio no, marker itself is undefined it's not name property , also u can see in image above , markers are defined and they have name defined

Comment: @aishwatsingh — You are passing an object to the Marker function, and that object has a name property, but you are assigning the return value of calling Marker to the array, not the object with the name property.

Comment: ok seems like u r setting event of marker to map first and then setting marker to map , do it opposite, just try putting `markers[i].setMap(map);` this before addlistener line , if it helps ?

Comment: @aishwatsingh I get the same error that way. Nice suggestion though

Comment: one more thing can u try this 
`google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function() {
     console.log(markers[i]); 
      //vl help to figure out if it's marker object issue or name property 
  });`
sorry i don't know much , just trying to help

Comment: Don't you have anything online so we can see it working and test from there?

Comment: @aishwatsingh Same error with log "undefined".

Comment: @emporio Try this: http://pastebin.com/pYbWizDC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works (`this` in the click listener refers to the `google.maps.Marker` that was clicked):

```
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) { 
  // add eventlistener for the infowindow we added earlier
  google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function() {
    this.name.open(map, this);
  });
  // add marker to map
  markers[i].setMap(map);
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/3w2teebL/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 3,
    // zoom in on current location if available (not done yet...)
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(5, 5)
  });

  var markers = [
    // put all markers in a markers array
    // @foreach ($markers as $marker)
    // New York, NY, USA (40.7127837, -74.00594130000002)
    new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {
        lat: 40.7127837,
        lng: -74.0059413
      },
      // infowindow for each marker with its name
      name: new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "New York, NY, USA"
      })
    }),
    // Newark, NJ, USA (40.735657, -74.1723667)
    new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {
        lat: 40.735657,
        lng: -74.1723667
      },
      // infowindow for each marker with its name
      name: new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "Newark, NJ, USA"
      })
    }),
    //  Baltimore, MD, USA (39.2903848, -76.61218930000001)
    new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {
        lat: 39.2903848,
        lng: -76.6121893
      },
      // infowindow for each marker with its name
      name: new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "Baltimore, MD, USA"
      })
    }),
    //    @endforeach
  ];
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    // add eventlistener for the infowindow we added earlier
    google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function() {
      this.name.open(map, this);
    });
    // add marker to map
    markers[i].setMap(map);
    bounds.extend(markers[i].getPosition());
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this ?

```
 for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            // add eventlistener for the infowindow we added earlier
            (function(i) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function() {
                    //console.log(markers[i])
                    markers[i].name.open(map, markers[i]);
                });
                // add marker to map
                markers[i].setMap(map);
            })(i);

  }
```